# How do I fix Network Error in post request?

Tags: reactjs, express

I'm trying to build a Spotify web app that shows artists search result based on the keyword that an user submitted. When I submit the search keyword, my post request is pending and get failed eventually on Chrome. Here's my code

main.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import SingerCard from "./SingerCard";
import axios from "axios";

export class Main extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      keyword: "",
      artists: [],
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ keyword: e.target.value });
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    axios
      .post(
        "http://localhost:4000/search_result",
        {
          keyword: this.state.keyword,
        },
        {
          headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        }
      )
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    let res = await fetch("http://localhost:4000/api");
    let artists = await res.json();
    this.setState({ artists });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="main">
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label htmlFor="search">Search an artist: </label>
          <span>
            <input
              type="search"
              value={this.state.keyword}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              name="keyword"
            />

            <button type="submit" value="Submit">
              Search
            </button>
          </span>
        </form>
        <br />
        <div className="genres">
          <h2 className="header text-capitalize">
            top 10 tracks of famous singers
          </h2>
        </div>
        <div className="container">
          {this.state.artists.map((elem) => (
            <SingerCard
              images={elem.images}
              name={elem.name}
              artists={this.state.artists}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
        <br />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Main;
```

SingerCard.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Modal from "react-bootstrap/Modal";
import notFound from "../../notFound.jpg";

const SingerCard = (props) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const showModal = () => {
    setIsOpen(true);
  };

  const hideModal = () => {
    setIsOpen(false);
  };

  //check if the image array is empty since some artists' image data provided by the API call are empty
  let singer_img = props.images.length === 0 ? notFound : props.images[0].url;

  return (
    <>
      <button type="button" onClick={showModal} style={{ padding: "1px" }}>
        <div className="card" style={{ width: "8rem" }}>
          <img class="card-img-top" src={singer_img} alt="Card image" />
          <div
            className="card-body"
            style={{ height: "4rem", fontSize: "14px" }}
          >
            <p className="card-text">{props.name}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </button>
      <Modal show={isOpen} onHide={hideModal}>
        <Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Title>{props.name}'s songs</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>dc</Modal.Body>

        <Modal.Footer>
          <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={hideModal}>
            Close
          </button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
};

export default SingerCard;
```

server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const SpotifyWebApi = require("spotify-web-api-node");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();

const port = 4000 || process.env.PORT;
require("dotenv").config();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// credentials
const spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi({
  clientId: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
  redirectUri: "http://localhost:8888/callback",
});

app.post("/search_result", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body.keyword);

  spotifyApi
    .clientCredentialsGrant()
    .then(function (data) {
      // Set the access token on the API object so that it's used in all future requests
      spotifyApi.setAccessToken(data.body["access_token"]);

      return spotifyApi.searchArtists(req.body.keyword);
    })
    .then(
      function (data) {
        console.log("Artist search result: ", data.body);
        app.get("/api", (req, res) => {
          res.json(data.body.artists.items);
        });
      },
      function (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    );
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`It's running on port ${port}`));
```

Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:83)
It's the error description on Chrome console. I'm sorry for the long question.

Comment: Could you also add this file createError.js ? The error is in it.

Comment: It's not my file. It's what the console says on Chrome.

Comment: You are not returning reponse from your post api (/search_result). you have declared get api inside your post api. So remove that get('/api') from your then block and simply return response

Answer (score 0):

First of all in the developer console of chrome go to Network tab and there you will see more details regarding the error. 
while you test your app on your local host address the issue may be due to CORS.
Try to add to your axios post request 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*' header.